# Julia: Generate normally distributed random number with restricted range

Tags: random, range, julia, normal-distribution

> **Question:** How can I generate a random number in the interval [0,1] from a Gaussian distribution in Julia?

I gather [randn](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/index.html#Base.randn) is the way to generate normally distributed random numbers, but the documentation's description of how to specify a range is quite opaque.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Distributions](https://juliastats.github.io/Distributions.jl/stable/starting.html) package. If you don't already have it:

```
using Pkg ; Pkg.add("Distributions")
```

then:

```
using Distributions
mu = 0    #The mean of the truncated Normal
sigma = 1 #The standard deviation of the truncated Normal
lb = 0    #The truncation lower bound
ub = 1    #The truncation upper bound
d = Truncated(Normal(mu, sigma), lb, ub)  #Construct the distribution type
x = rand(d, 100) #Simulate 100 obs from the truncated Normal
```

or all in one line:

```
x = rand(Truncated(Normal(0, 1), 0, 1), 100)
```

Comment: Why is it that if I do this and then try `std(rand(Truncated(Normal(0, 1), 0, 1), 100))` I consistently get an answer less than 1? Like I understand I may not exactly get 1, but I get something in the range of 0.2 which seems much lower than 1.

Comment: @newtothis You're restricting the Standard Normal to the range [0,1], which is a pretty big restriction on that distribution. Note that the standard deviation of a uniform random variable on [0,1]  is about 0.29, so an outcome near that number for the truncated Standard Normal on the interval [0,1] sounds about right. In general try truncating the Standard Normal on the interval [a,b]. When `a` and `b` are very close to each other the standard deviation will be close to `0`, but it will approach 1 as `a` goes to -infinity and `b` goes to infinity.